# Register-PackageSource: Doesn't save credentials in `nuget.config` file

Tags: powershell, nuget, powershell-5.1, powershell-7.2

When I enter …

```
Register-PackageSource -Name 'Test' -Location 'https://artifactory.contoso.com/artifactory/api/nuget/test/' -ProviderName 'NuGet' -Credential (Get-Credential) -ForceBootstrap -Trusted
```

… no credentials are getting saved to the `nuget.config` file.

What do I need to change to have this PowerShell command save the provided credentials along?

Comment: While [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/register-packagesource) don't discuss saving credentials, I suspect doing so is simply not supported.

Comment: I guess that's a bug then. Why the `Credential` parameter, if it doesn't work? – I created a [bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17712).